# Graphics ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception, graphic

I am writing a program similar to **Atari Breakout**. Therefore I am creating an `ArrayList<Rect>`. The code is:

```
package spiel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import shapes.Rect;

public class Spiel extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    Spiel()
    {
        super("Bounce Game");
    }

    static Spiel spiel = new Spiel();
    static ArrayList<Rect> rects = new ArrayList<Rect>();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    public  void drawRects()
    {
        Graphics Stift = getGraphics();
        for(int i = 0; i <= 14; i++)
        {
            Stift.drawRect(rects.get(i).hoch, rects.get(i).breit, rects.get(i).punktx, rects.get(i).punkty);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Spiel frame = new Spiel();
        frame.setSize(1200,1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        for(int i = 0; i<=14; i++)
        {
            int h = 0;
            int b = 0;
            if(i <= 4) h =0;
            if(i <= 9) h =1;
            if(i <= 14)h =2;

            if(i <= 4) b =i;
            if(i <= 9) b =i-5;
            if(i <= 14)b =i-10;

            rects.add(new Rect(100, 200, 0+h*100, 0+b*200));
            spiel.drawRects();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {       
    }
}
```

**The class Rect contains:**

```
package shapes;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Rect extends Rectangle {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public int hoch;
    public int breit;
    public int punktx;
    public int punkty;

    public Rect(int h, int b, int x, int y)
    {
        this.hoch = h;
        this.breit = b;
        this.punktx = x;
        this.punkty = y;
    }
}
```

But I get a `NullPointerException` when I invoke `get(i)` and `drawRects()` and I don't know why.

Comment: There's only one reason for getting a `NullPointerException`: the object you tried to invoke a method on was not there (i.e. the reference was null). This is a nice opportunity to practice your debugger-handling skills.

Comment: I figured this out already. But I don't understand why the Object isn't there.

Comment: Do not use `getGraphics()` to draw, override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method instead and use the graphics object in the argument

Answer (score 2):

Look at the line:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 14; i++)
```

You want:

```
for(int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++)
```

This is because you call the drawRects method while you are still creating the rects - so the first time you call it, you will only have 1 rect, and certainly not 15. Try to define everything you will be using before you even initialize the frame or any UI elements.

Comment: or in this case a for-each loop would work well `for(Rectangle r : rects)`

Answer (score 0):

You invoke `spiel.drawRects()` inside the loop in which you are initializing list `rects`.  The `drawRects()` method assumes that the list has already been fully populated, which is not the case on, say, the first iteration of the loop.  At minimum, it appears you want to move the `drawRects()` invocation outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you. But now I get an IndexOutOfBounds excpetion. It seems like the list is never filled.

Comment: @NovaShadowflame use a for-each loop and it shouldn't go out of bounds

Comment: I never worked with for-each. Could you explain it please?

Comment: @NovaShadowflame `for(Rectangle r : rects) Stift.drawRect(r.get(i)...);`  It's a for loop that gives you each object in the array/collection one at a time, instead of giving you an index of the array to get the data from

Comment: Thanks, I got no error. But it won't draw the Rectangles.

Comment: @NovaShadowflame, I see no reason why changing the posted code *only* by moving the `spiel.drawRects()` invocation immediately *after* the loop would produce a program that throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @phflack, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` would seem to signal a problem initializing the list.  Although it could be avoided by using a for-each loop, that only treats the symptom, not the underlying problem.

Comment: I think that the ArrayList is empty as said in the exception. I think the IdexOutOfBoundsException was there from the beginning but never occured due to the NullPointerException.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that and I'd recommend changing `extends JFrame` to `extends JPanel` and using `JPanel.paintComponent(Graphics g)` to draw instead of using `JFrame.getGraphics()`

Comment: And how do I transform my Rect to Graphics?